# Manually show VS tooltip when Resharper error prevents intellisense on hover

Tags: visual-studio, debugging, resharper

In Visual Studio, normally when I hover over a variable it will display the type while editting code and the value while debugging.

**How it should look when you hover over tablename:**

[image: How it should look]

Resharper messes some of that up by overriding the tooltip whenever it has a formatting suggestion or error it thinks you ought to pay attention to.

**How it looks when the error is blocking the tooltip**

[image: Tool tip blocked]

Couple questions I can't seem to find the answer to:

- What's the name of the pop-up that shows variable information (is tooltip correct?)
- Is there a way to manually invoke it? (normally <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>Shift</kbd> + <kbd>Space</kbd> works)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Just found it while looking into posting this question...

It is a member of Edit > Intellisense called QuickInfo and you can access it with <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>I</kbd>

**Here's the Menu Function**

[image: Quick Info]

**Here's a working example**

[image: Working Properly]

Comment: Not sure what VS keyboard settings you are using but my Quick Info is on CTRL+K, I. Have you also tried Resharper's Show Quick Documentation (under ReSharper->Edit->Show Quick Documentation... or CTRL+SHIFT+F1)?